# how to find what libraries are installed/available on a machine for C or CPP?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, static-libraries

this is not a outright tech question but i wanted to know if there is a easier way to find what all libraries are present in a system for a particular language and its facilities .... something like a man page would be great , but to look for info you got to know what exist there first. (3rd party libraries for example....)

my way : for C or CPP - i know if there is a compiler like gcc or g++ all the standard libraries that are installed as part of the compiler itself so i can simply look into the section 2 - 3 of the manual , but those are standard libraries , you can also read about them as part of a book for C and CPP .

What i was really interested in was to find a way to discover libraries i dont know off and try and learn about them .
like 3rd party libraries like boost  could/might be found in places like /usr/bin ...  so i was doing a find for libXXX.a or a .so file , then doing google to find what it is and where and how i can use it ....... but this is feels stupid  :(

there must be a easier way to find things ?

PS : i am not owner of the machine so i dont do installations myself , think of a Work/University server .... lot of guys access that. , by the way the OS is Solaris 9

Comment: Almost every dynamic library on a Unixy system is written in/for C and/or C++. `ls /usr/lib` should be fine.

Comment: This is probably not a good way of discovering libraries. I have over 1000 library files in `/usr/lib` alone, very few of which I would care to learn about.

Comment: then how would you decide/find out on what else you should be knowing other than stdlib's of C or CPP which are mentioned in books ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We choose to learn those libraries that we intend to use. It sounds like you want to know which **packages** are installed on the system by querying the **package manager**. Without knowing which operating system is in use, it's difficult to be any more specific.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems

Answer (score 5):

If you are on linux you can do at the terminal:

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

On my system this gives the following output:

```
gmodule-no-export-2.0          GModule - Dynamic module loader for GLib
xrender                        Xrender - X Render Library
#many many more
xcb                            XCB - X-protocol C Binding
gnome-mime-data-2.0            gnome-mime-data - Base set of file types and applications for GNOME
```

So the name of libray and a short description.

Comment: Very concise and straight to the point

Comment: Actually `dpkg --list` lists all the packages

Comment: @RubemPacelli Yes, dpkg --list list all packages, however it also list packages that have nothing to do with libraries, and pkg-config does excactly that. You can use it to list packages, but also to obtain extra information about the libraries, such as compilation and linking flags. It's very usefull for C(++) programmers.

Comment: That is strange because I've just installed the [`libpoppler-cpp-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libpoppler-cpp-dev/filelist) package, which contains C/C++ libraries, and `pkg-config --list-all` wasn't able to list it to me. On the other hand, I found it using `dpkg --list`

Comment: @hetepeperfan Ok, I just find out that this packages is properly listed by the name `poppler-cpp`, as it is mentioned in the `.pc` (pkg-config) file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/poppler-cpp.pc`. That actually makes sense since we omit the prefix `lib` and the suffix `.so` when linking a library. However, `pkg-config` does not provide the Linux package name (in my case, `libpoppler-cpp-dev`) used to install the library, which might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just browsing for something interesting to learn about, it might be more worthwhile to either browse the rpm database for your distro, or rpmfind.net.